# Joomla! JFactory::getDate wrong

Tags: php, joomla-2.5, joomla-api, date

According to the documentation [JFactory/getDate](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getDate) `$tzOffset` default value is `0`. However, the following example:

```
$date_default_offset = JFactory::getDate('now');
echo $date_default_offset->toRFC822(true);
echo "<br />";
$date_zero_offset = JFactory::getDate('now', 0);
echo $date_zero_offset->toRFC822(true);
```

... gives different outputs:

```
Mon, 13 Oct 2014 18:31:37 +0000
Mon, 13 Oct 2014 19:31:41 +0100
```

Shouldn't both dates be the same? What else should I take into account?

The actual date is:

```
echo date("r"); // Mon, 13 Oct 2014 20:40:33 +0200
```

That's right because the server is in Spain (+1 GMT and +1 Daylight Saving Time in Summer).

The problem arised whe trying to adjust a module to take into account the current time in Canary Islands, that should be `Mon, 13 Oct 2014 19:31:41 +0100`according to the given example.

I'm using Joomla! 2.5.27, the Server Time Zone is set to Canary (GMT+0).

Comment: Did you try `echo JHtml::date('now', 'Y-d-m H:i:s e', 'Atlantic/Canary');`?

Comment: @Farahmand That gives exactly the date/time in Canary Islands. Need to study a bit more to understand the differences. However, note that the question is related to the 'default' behaviour in the getDate() construction. Shouldn't both getDate() calls give the same result?

Comment: Check my answer, @pQB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file `/libraries/joomla/factory.php` and search for `getDate()` function:

```
public static function getDate($time = 'now', $tzOffset = null)
```

The default value of time zone offset (`$tzOffset`) is `null` and not `0`. It may be due to a mistake in [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getDate) or it's for versions older than 2.5.

In Joomla 3, `$date_zero_offset = JFactory::getDate('now', 0);` raises an error:

> DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone, integer given

So for Canary Islands, you can use this:

```
$date_zero_offset = JFactory::getDate('now', 'Atlantic/Canary');
```

Comment: You are right. Thank for pointing the file. No doubts. However, the documentation I pointed in the question clearly states that `$tzOffset` is a `signed integer` which default value is `0`, and was the root of the problem.

Comment: No problem. Joomla documentations like other documentations over the web may have faults. My suggestion for developers is using an IDE like Eclipse and check the core functions instantly.

Answer (score 3):

It might be an idea to get the offset from your Global Config like so:

```
$date = JFactory::getDate($input='now', 'UTC');
$tz   = JFactory::getConfig()->getValue('config.offset');
$date->setOffset($tz);

echo $date->toFormat();
```

To make life a little easier and have less code, I would suggest using `JHtml::date`

```
echo JHtml::date($input = 'now', 'm/d/Y', false);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your example outputs `2014-10-13 19:05:52` however, the current time at Canary Islands in `20:05:52`. Note +1 of difference because the +1 Daylight Saving Time in Summer.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get the date correctly in Joomla! **v.3.9.14**, here's my *(proven)* solution:

```
$oUser_TZ  = JFactory::getUser()->getTimezone();
$aUser_tz  = (array)$oUser_TZ; // almost sure this step is not that necessary
$full_date = JFactory::getDate('now', $aUser_tz['timezone']); // pretty sure $oUser_tz->timezone will work

// I had try to use $full_date->Format('Y-m-d H:i:s') but it was giving me the non-converted-to-wanted-timezone date, so
$date_converted = substr($full_date, 0, 19);
```

`$date_converted` gives me the date in format `Y-m-d H:i:s` and in the wanted timezone.

Comment: Replace the entire snippet above with `JHtml::date('now', 'Y-m-d H:i:s')`  The 2nd parameter is the desired format.  The 3rd (omitted) parameter defaults to `true` -- this tells the function to use the user's designated timezone.  https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JHtml::date  I just tested my advice locally to be equivalent.

Comment: After a bit more thought, I don't think this question is focusing on generating a logged in user's datetime. It is about the 2nd param of `getData()`.  Your answer would be more appropriate at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/10658/12352 ...but my advised one-liner is already there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you for your correction and advice @mickmackusa!, I tried it and it work like a charm!, very very helpful! I'm still struggling trying to understand the documentation of Jommla! classes and how to uses them properly.