# Joomla Timezone

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, date, jfactory

I would like to check the time within a sub controller's method. The calendar field in my JForm saves the datetime to sql and uses UTC. So now we have 15:11h in Germany and in the database would be stored "2015-07-01 13:11:00".

Well, fine.

Now I'm using DATE_FORMAT_LC2 in my views to print the time in "German time". This works fine, too.

Now my controller wants to check if the entry is older than current time. Unfortunately I always get "2015-07-01 13:11:00", the time that is saved in the database, when calling $this->savedtime;

How can I "generate" the german time in my controller? At this moment this is my source:

```
$now            =           JFactory::getDate();            
$itemdate       =           JFactory::getDate($item->savedtime);

if($now > $itemdate)
{
//do fancy stuff
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JHtml::date()` will automatically use your timezone setting.

```
JHtml::date('now', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083108/joomla-timezone)